# Django: Why is form.id within a formset empty?

Tags: django

I came across a strange issue.

I create a regular formset and everything works as intended:

```
deal_formset = formset_factory(DealCForm, extra=0)
...
formset = deal_formset(data)
```

Within the template though I don't seem to get the id of the current form, which I am iterating through.  why is form.id empty?

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% if formset %}
  {% for form in formset %}  
   ...
    {{form.id}}   
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't think there is default _id_ field for form. Have you defined it in _DealCForm_? If form is from instance you can refer it as, _form.instance.id_, however its not a form field so need to render it.

Comment: yeah I think you are right. Nonetheless I found out `{{ fs.prefix }}` contains the id, which I was looking for. e.g. `form-0` or `form-1`